# RadMenu ItemCreated not firing

Tags: c#, telerik

I am trying to utilize the `ItemClick` event of the `RadMenu` control; however, according [to this article](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/menu-itemclick-event-not-fired.html), I cannot do so if I have set the `NavigateUrl` property.

> ItemClick Event Does Not Fire
>
> ...
>
> You have set the NavigateUrl property of the menu item.
>
> This effectively disables PostBacks (OnItemClick event) because the item navigate to the particular URL rather than posting back.

In the article, Telerik recommends a simple workaround which utilizes the `ItemCreated` event.  Unfortunately, the `ItemCreated` event is not firing for me and I am not sure why.

Here is my `RadMenu` and code-behind:

```
<telerik:RadMenu ID="RadMenu1" runat="server" OnItemCreated="RadMenu1_ItemCreated">
    <Items>
        <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" NavigateUrl="http://www.test.com" Text="Test" Target="_blank"></telerik:RadMenuItem>
        <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" NavigateUrl="http://www.test.com" Text="Test 2" Target="_blank"></telerik:RadMenuItem>
    </Items>
</telerik:RadMenu>

protected void RadMenu1_ItemCreated(object sender, RadMenuEventArgs e)
{
    e.Item.Attributes["NavigateUrl"] = e.Item.NavigateUrl;
    e.Item.NavigateUrl = "";
}
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I dont see because your code don't fires the ItemCreated but you can use this code for do the same in any other event like Page_Load

```
foreach (RadMenuItem item in RadMenu1.Items)
{
     item.Attributes["NavigateUrl"] = item.NavigateUrl;
     item.NavigateUrl = "";
}
```